# Making time bins bigger in a large dataset with python

Tags: python

I have a dataset with an array of time bins of size 1/4096 seconds against the number of photons in each time bin. Now, I want to change the resolution by making the time bins a factor of 2 larger, by summing up 2 of them and taking the mean, both with the times and with the photon count. I tried a couple of things like:

```
tnew = [] 
for n in range(int((len(t))/2)):
    tnew[n] = (t[2*n]+t[2*n+1])/2
```

and:

```
for l in range(int((len(t))/2):
    np.append(t, (np.sum(t[2*l:4096*(2*l+1)]))/2)
```

but I can't seem to make this work. I'm really new to Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take the means of adjacent elements in a NumPy array, you can do the following:

```
In [2]: a = np.arange(10)
In [3]: a
Out[3]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
In [4]: (a[:-1:2] + a[1::2])/2.
Out[4]: array([ 0.5,  2.5,  4.5,  6.5,  8.5])
```

Here, `a[:-1:2]` is all the elements at even indexes and `a[1::2]` is all the elements at odd indexes.

In your case, since your array's length is a power of 2, you might choose to allow binning by m = 2, 4, 8, etc with by reshaping and taking the mean along the corresponding axis:

```
In [5]: n = 1024
In [6]: a = np.arange(n)
In [7]: m = 8
In [8]: b = a.reshape((a.shape[0]/m, m))
In [9]: b.mean(axis=1)
Out[9]:
    array([    3.5,    11.5,    19.5,    27.5,    35.5,    43.5,    51.5,
              59.5,    67.5,    75.5,    83.5,    91.5,    99.5,   107.5,
              ...
          ])
```

Comment: How about if I want to change them by a factor of 10? I think I would need a different approach, or is something like this still applicable?